# Android Facebook login does not work on LG G3

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-studio, facebook-login

I'm developing a new app on Android Studio and I created an app with a Facebook login: Facebook SDK v4. There is a problem with my connection with Facebook on the device LG G3. On some devices it works really well as - " emulators, device Samsung Note3" but when I connect to the device LG G3 I receive an error"key hash is invalid" what can I do? The version I'm trying to test on is: LG G3 Android version 5.0.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: try to use only a "release" version and not a debug. don't forget to add the "release" key info to your fb account.

Comment: hay thanks i'm using app release apk but it is not working ever .i download the app release apk to my device and install in the normal way

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674131/android-facebook-integration-invalid-key-hash Check this.

Comment: hay i have a key hash from Facebook thanks , it does work on some devices as Samsung  and  on lg g3 it does not work

Comment: Hi Ori, can you reproduce this in the newest sdk?