# Android w/ Facebook SDK: key hash error suddenly

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hash, facebook-android-sdk

The error of using an invalid hash key error when using the Facebook SDK in Android apps seems to be rather common. And the solution I found in this [Stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674131/android-facebook-integration-invalid-key-hash) worked perfectly. I created the hash key programmatically in my app and did a Copy&Paste of the key into the interface of the Facebook Developer page of my app.

Despite finding this and alternative solutions, I couldn't find a good explanation why I got this error all of a sudden.

- When I use the keystore command below, I still get the same hash key that was already registered on my Facebook developer page and which worked neatly so far (so right now I'm having 2 registered hash keys)

  ```
  keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
  ```
- I didn't change the development environment, i.e., the PC to develop my app.
- Just a couple of hours before I got this error, I gave the app to a new registered tester, who could logged into my app perfectly fine
- I'm currently only developing and testing, so the app is not made public yet
- Singing in and out still worked fine on the emulator. Only on my own phone I use for testing the app on a physical device I suddenly got this error after I signed out and wanted to sign in again.

I'm just trying to understand what's going on here so I know what to expect and what to do once I go public with the app. As I understand, there's a debug key and a production key. But even if the new key is the production key, why did this happen?

Why are the hash keys - the one I generate using the `keytool` command and the one that I generate within the app - different?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug on Facebook's end.I've been dealing with the same issue for the past 24 hours. I tried everything from creating a new Facebook app and using the new Facebook Id and App Secret (worked for a minute and then I started getting the same error message again), to deleting app on device and even updating Facebook SDK.

**Solution**

I finally got past it by `copying the keyhash I was getting in the error message and replacing it with the old one on the developer console`.

You can copy it directly from the `debug` tab in Android monitor.

If you are not sure how to get this, just log it from the callback method:

```
        ...
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());
            // ...
        }
```

Comment: Ojonugwa, thanks! As I mentioned, solving the issue was reasonably straightforward. It's just that I could find any solid information on the Why.