# Error Login facebook Angular 2

Tags: facebook, angular, ionic2, angular2-services, ionic2-providers

I'm trying to implement the Facebook log in my application with the following example: [ng2-facebook-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-facebook-sdk)

When redirecting to the page of facebook shows me:

> Can not load the URL: The domain of this URL is not included in the
>   domains of the application. In order to load this URL, add all domains
>   and subdomains of your application in the "Application domains" field
>   in the application settings.

I am working on a mobile application in Angular 2 and Ionic 2 therefore I have no domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend using the Ionic native `Facebook` plugin.It has all the steps on the official doc and very easy to follow.Hence it is native you don't need to worry about the performance too.

Here is the [**official doc**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/).

**Update:** You can use Graph API to request additional details.

[**Profile /{profile-id}**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/profile)

[**Getting a User's Birthday**](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4#getting-a-users-birthday)

[**cordova-plugin-facebook4**](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4)

Comment: Hello
The link that you sent me works perfectly, but it only returns me that the state is successful and a token, how can I get profile data? Name, lastname, mail, etc.

Comment: You can get all those data.please see the **Update** section above.

Comment: It worked the first few times, then it gives me the error: Facebook error: Invalid key hash. The key hash XXXXXXXX does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Comment: It's a problem on your key hash.You must do it properly using above link.Hope this too help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23863110/1077309