# Google Login and Facebook Login Error after i release my app?

Tags: android, facebook, firebase-authentication

When I build my app and try it work fine no any wrong there, but after I release my app on google play store and try login with Facebook it gives me an error. The error is a wrong hash key because the hash key change 
(I got hash key for sign app by many way give me same has key and work fine)
this first problem.

My second issue is when try use gmail sign in (google login) get field with error.

(You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please check. Detailed error: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE)

It was working fine in release app by put it in my real phone but after 
upload it in play store not work I added the the sign  SHA1 fingerprint  and all step.

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.0'      for Facebook
```

and

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'     

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
```

How can fix this problem?

Comment: not sure if this can help but seems related 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674131/android-facebook-integration-invalid-key-hash

Comment: thanks i found the answer but other way i use

Answer (score 3):

i change the Upload certificate  SHA1 fingerprint with the

App signing certificate SHA1 fingerprint

from play store an part App signing like in pic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbXb4.png)