# I always get ivalid key hash when I try to do facebook login in my android app

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am trying to implement in my android application, an activity that shows the albums of a facebook fan page.

I have started trying to log in, following the documentation of Facebook developers.
[Quick Start for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/APLICATION-ID/?platform=android)

I've made several attempts, and I always get the same problem. In the first installation of the application, the login is executed successfully.
Then, when I log out, and try to enter again, I get the following error:

[image: Error obtained]

I've tried to fix it by removing the facebook developer application and creating a new one, with a new hash key.
However, after a successful first run, I get the same error again.

I think there is not in my movie app under development, a link to the hash key I generated and log here->[image: Hash key]

Can somebody help me?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674131/android-facebook-integration-invalid-key-hash
did this help?

Comment: Yes!! Thanks!! @10101010