# invalid hash key after one successful login with facebook in react native

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, react-native

I am trying to do login with facebook in my app and want profile data. For that I am generating hash key using command. After getting key i am putting it on developers website but it gives me error. I done all other things as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674131/android-facebook-integration-invalid-key-hash) but all these things are not working for me.

I can do first login successfully (key generated by keytool command) but after that it showing invalid hash key error.

please help How can I get out from this.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is with openssl do not download latest version. If you have a 64 bit machine you must  [`download openssl-0.9.8e X64`](https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads) not the latest version.

then generate key using command

> $ keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64

It will ask for password put "android" (not other)

that's all Now it will work.