# Facebook & LinkedIn integration not working in beta release

Tags: android, linkedin-api, facebook-login

I have some strange issue regarding Facebook & Linkedin integration,

I have integrated login through Facebook & LinkedIn in my application.

Login Working fine in **debug & release build**.
But when I **upload my application in beta release** with signed apk(release build), login functionality is not working neither Facebook nor LinkedIn.

I have generated key hash using

**FOR DEBUG**

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

**FOR RELEASE**

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <aliasName> -keystore <keystoreFilePath> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

I am getting `Invalid key hash.` error.

Here is the screenshot of the same,
[image: INVALID KEY HASH]

Comment: Refere below answers.<br>
May be it helps you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44782435/6016830

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of research on this I come to know something new & interesting. Here it goes,

When we upload our application on *Google play console*, It signs it & generates a *signature certificate* for application. As a part of this process our SHA1 value gets replaced & gets new SHA1 value *assigned by signature certificate*.

One can find this value at ***Google Play Console > All Applications > You Application > Version Management > Signature of the app > Certificate of signature of the app > SHA-1 fingerprint of the certificate***

**NOTE : Please copy manually** because coping from given button (next to SHA1 key) also includes "SHA1:" text, which is actually not part of SHA1 of the application.

Once copied properly, convert your **SHA1 to base-64** format. You can do so using this link [SHA1 Convert to Base64](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en).

At the end copy hash key value named as **Output (base64)** on [SHA1 Convert to Base64](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en).

Now add this hash key to your `Facebook` & `LinkedIn` developer portal.

Comment: Please up-vote this answer, If helped. Happy Coding!