# Android Signed APK doesn't display maps in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, signed-apk

> **Google map is not visible after generating signed APK in Android. I
>   have made the SHA1 key using these steps.**
>
> 1) On the right-hand side, I have clicked on Gradle
>  2) I have
>   expanded my project folder
>  3) After that I have clicked on Run
>   Configurations
>  4) Lastly, I have double clicked the SigningReport
>   along with the project name.
>  5) I have received the SHA1 key from
>   the run configurations at the bottom of the Android Studio.
>
> **The same I have added it to the live play store account listed below,**
>
> 6) Created a new project name into the Google Cloud Platform
>  7)
>   Generated new API Key
>  8) Clicked on Application restrictions where
>   I select Android
>  9) Lastly, I have added my project package name
>   along with the SHA1 generated through the above 1 to 5 steps.

But when I generated signed APK, it will not display any map and shows the blank page of Google Map. On the other hand, Google Map works in the non-signed or regular APKs.

[image]

Comment: Do you see any error message in the logs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933380/sha1-key-for-debug-release-android-studio-mac/34933381

Comment: you need to add SHA with your signed keystore credentials and add it to your console.

Comment: Refere this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44330035/5825949 
Hope this will works for you

Comment: @himangi: I have gone through the URL and right now, there are 3 options available to me instead of this SHA1 key and more 2 options.

Comment: I don't know what to upload in PERK tool and which option to select?

Comment: @himangi, this is my BETA release, so I haven't uploaded my app to the production as it is in BETA mode.

Answer (score 0):

When we upload our application on Google play console, It signs it & generates a signature certificate for application. As a part of this process our SHA1 value gets replaced & gets new SHA1 value assigned by signature certificate.

One can find this value at Google Play Console > All Applications > You Application > Version Management > Signature of the app > Certificate of signature of the app > SHA-1 fingerprint of the certificate

**NOTE** : Please copy manually because coping from given button (next to SHA1 key) also includes "SHA1:" text, which is actually not part of SHA1 of the application.

Once copied properly, convert your SHA1 to base-64 format. You can do so using this link SHA1 Convert to Base64.

At the end copy hash key value named as Output (base64) on SHA1 Convert to Base64.

Now add this hash key to your Facebook & LinkedIn developer portal.

Comment: It's not working anymore. because I have uploaded new APK to the play store, after that I have saved my APK. And then move to the app signing page. It gives three radio button for uploading something.

Comment: Hi @ParthBhayani, I had gone through similar issue for Facebook & LinkedIn. Check this answer. This might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50211278/6016830

Comment: @buzzingsilently, plz check the image above into the question. I don't understand which option to select and what to upload.

Comment: hey try r=this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318370/google-sign-in-not-working-after-publishing-in-play-store/44330035#44330035