# Invalid key hash in facebook login

Tags: android, facebook-login

I am integrating Facebook login in my current application and I am getting key hash error and it is getting so irritating, as, even after adding the key which is missing, in Facebook developer console, I am getting the same error again and again.(Refer image)

[image]

I tried almost all solutions available on Stackoverflow but the solution is common in every answer and even after making the changes, I am not able to login through Facebook
Even I have added this hash key into my project.(Shown in image)

[image]

PS: My app is still under development and not active on play store.

Comment: Check this solution and follow these given steps:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44782435/3974530

Comment: have you activated our app in FB developer console ?

Comment: @Vihaari Varma, No, when i am trying to do so i am getting this message: You must provide a valid Privacy Policy URL in order take your app Live. Go to Basic Settings and make sure it is valid.

Comment: @InsaneCat, do i need to have an active developer account for integrating Facebook login?

Comment: There i a two option for this. first you can make it your app live in play store then after it is going to active or second thing you need to add testers in developer account for temporary basis.

Comment: @Kunal are you sure you saved the new hash to fb dev account correctly?

Comment: @VihaariVarma yes, i have checked it multiple times

Comment: Put a currect hashkey in FB develoepr account and add a tester in Setting/Roles/Role/add Tester this is working for you.

Answer (score 3):

You must be trying to login through release version of your app while your app is in development mode in Facebook developer account. Even if you have submitted hash of your release key, Login won't work until your app goes live on Facebook too. And for  that,you have to submit your privacy policy.

But, you can still test your debug version of your app by submitting hash of your debug key. To know how, Follow
[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506392/how-to-create-android-facebook-key-hash).

**UPDATE**

You have **mistyped** '43O' as '430' in your key hash submitted to FB developer account. Correct it. For everyone else - be careful, also `I` and `l` are looking almost identically.

Comment: I run the command in this answer to get the hash of debug key: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18101444/6429885, and updated the same key in Facebook developer console, still no luck

Comment: @Kunal n which version of your app are you trying to log in? Debug or release

Comment: I am using Debug mode

Comment: huh... got the error. You mistyped capital 'O'  as '0' near '43O/' in your key hash, check it once

Comment: Yes, i was making the mistake there only... remove that hash key and reentered and it worked!!!