# Facebook auth issue with facebook (Not facebook lite)

Tags: java, android, facebook, authentication

I have a strange issue with my app. When I try to login using Facebook it works perfectly when Facebook lite is installed.However, when I uninstall Facebook lite and install Facebook app it gives me the error of "invalid key hash".This is the dependency I use for Facebook.

```
 implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.39.0'
```

Comment: There is another issue reported here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674131/android-facebook-integration-invalid-key-hash" please refer.

Comment: I guess I have a different issue here

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue in multiple apps. Looks like there are some problems in facebook app update which are not allowing users to login using facebook app even if we as developers added generated keyhash using production keystore in facebook developer console.

I followed this discussion here and solved my problem. https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login/issues/297. You can check solution from madmax124 and knight1O1. I have solved my problem following madmax124's answer.